# Grupos en Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, group-by

Estoy elaborando reportes para un proyecto y necesito dividirlos por grupos según un determinado campo, en el siguiente informe necesito que se dividan por centros de costo, para lo que uso el id de los centros de costo en a expresión como dicen los tutoriales que he visto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que en los reportes los agrupa por centros de costo, pero en algunos casos los divide, es decir si un centro de costo tiene 15 registro, a veces los agrupa bien o a veces los agrupa en 1,2,3 o hasta 4 grupos del mismo Centro de Costo, y pone de 7, 3, 5 registros en cada uno(esto es indiscriminado). Hay alguna manera de controlar que los grupos se creen uno por cada código como debe ser, Que me falta Configurar o como puedo hacer mas exacta la consulta para  que esto no suceda

P.D. La información que recibe el jasper viene de un sp desarrollado en SQL SERVER que se carga a traves de plsql.

Este es un vistazo del reporte y del lo que pasa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me sucede en todos los reportes donde uso la función Group del Jasper

Agradezco su ayuda y orientación con este problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si los datos no vienen ordenados conforme a los grupos desde el SQL usa:

- **Sort Fields** desde **Outline**:

  1. Selecciona el menú: *Window > Show View > Outline*
  2. Click derecho sobre **Sort Fields**, seleccionar **Create Sort Field**.
  3. Se abrirá la ventana *New Sort Field Wizard*, selecciona el campo para ordenar, en éste caso el del grupo.
  4. Presiona el botón **Finish**.

ó

- La pestaña **Sorting** desde el editor de consulta SQL.

Comment: Me puedes regalar si tienes algún link  con teoría o guías sobre esa función

Comment: Déjame revisar, pero realmente no es complicado: simplemente es agregar/quitar fields como si fuera un `ORDER BY` de SQL.

Comment: gracias, quedo pendiente si me puedes dar una guia